# Unable to access HTML files kept inside folder using templateUrl in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, visual-studio, http-status-code-404, angular-routing

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 to develop an angular application.

Below is folder structure

[image]

I have placed two `login.html`. One inside `Views` folder another with same level with `index.html`. For the sake of snapshot I have placed two `login.html` together. Otherwise, there is only one `login.html` in my application.

Below is code that I have written in app.config. I am using AngularAMD & requirejs for my application.

```js
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/login', angularAMD.route({
                templateUrl: '/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl',
                controllerUrl: 'controller/LoginController',
                navtab: 'login'
            }))
            .when('/home', angularAMD.route({
                templateUrl: '/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                controllerUrl: 'controller/HomeController',
                navtab: 'home'
            }))
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
    });
```

When I am using `templateUrl` as "/login.html" as shown in app.config then the application is loading the login.html perfectly.

However, when I am using `templateUrl` as "/views/login.html" ( or "views/login.html" or "../views/login.html" ), it is not working. It is showing 404 error in F12 tool in Chrome while loading `login.html`.

However, the path which is being shown is matching with my directory structure. Below is the snapshot of F12 tool.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me where I am making mistake when trying to access HTML files from the folder.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the login is in wich folder on the root with index or in views/ with home?

Comment: My goal is to keep login.html inside "views" folder. But when I am trying that it is throwing 404 error. Wheras, if I keep it inside root directory then I can run my application. However, in both two cases, I am changing the "templateUrl" as I have written above.

Comment: could you provide a plnk or fiddle.  also try clean cache in browser it some times help. lol. also have you try load home.html. and have the same result?

Comment: I have tried with cache clearing with no useful result. home.html is also behaving same way as login.html. Never tried with plunk or fiddle. However, trying to arrange.

Comment: Try making a folder under views called static, move the content in there? Forget the platform, but seen that before where you didn't pick up direct files, only content of sub-directories..